# How to check skos:prefLabel by SKOS API

Tags: java, vocabulary, skos

I am trying to check the `skos:prefLabel` of an SKOS vocabulary using the SKOSAPI (http://skosapi.sourceforge.net/). I have been looking for a method like `isPrefLabel()` but I did not found anything. Does anybody know any other SKOS library or how to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
SKOSManager man = new SKOSManager();
SKOSDataFactory factory = man.getSKOSDataFactory();
// Method
factory.getSKOSAnnotation(factory.getSKOSPrefLabelProperty().getURI(), "Some Label", "lang");
```